# lua-sec-prosody Unable to locate package

Tags: lua, jitsi

using ubuntu 14.04LTS
trying to install jitsimeet >https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/INSTALL.md

**but fails to install lua-sec-prosody package**

```
$sudo apt-get install lua-sec-prosody

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package lua-sec-prosody
```

sources.list contain this line at end.

deb http://packages.prosody.im/debian trusty main

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Changed the line in the sources.list to a previous version and it worked.

deb http://packages.prosody.im/debian precise main

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, lua-sec-prosody is an (old) fork of lua-sec that merges in some required changes. If it's not available for your platform, it means you should just use lua-sec :)

http://prosody.im/doc/depends/luasec/prosody