# Unable to create account in Jappix, metronome xmpp

Tags: amazon-ec2, lua, xmpp

I am trying to set up Jappix on amazon ec2. I have followed this guide and setup everything.

https://github.com/jappix/jappix/wiki

https://project.jappix.com/

I ran into this problem while setting up and solved it.
[lua-sec-prosody Unable to locate package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711653/lua-sec-prosody-unable-to-locate-package/23734936)

Now after everything is set up(modifying config files etc) I am not able to create an account.
When I try to register from my custom installation of jappix, It shows "Service unavailable".
I also tried to point Pidgin to my instance and tried to create an account but failed. However, it is able to connect because I verified that by

> service metronome stop

and

> service metronome start

Now I tried to use the admin interface through telnet

> telnet localhost 5582

and tried to create a user. I got this error

> Error: /usr/local/lib/metronome/core/usermanager.lua:80: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

Is there anything that I am missing?

PS: I have enabled the required ports on my ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

That ominous message means, you're trying to create a user on an unexistant or unactivated host.
(That's fixed in latest tip btw)